# Innerhtml in a div tag not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out an issue on a site which has just stopped working.

It's a bit tricky as I don't have server access at the moment, and it's a system I having to get my head around quickly.

basically a section of what looks like a javascript panel on a site has disappeared - and I'm trying to work out why.

I'm using firebug to try and track this down.

It seems to be anything within "innerhtml" on a tags is being ignored, if I put some content outside of innerhtml it shows!

eg

```
<div id="slide-browser-country-info" innerhtml="&lt;div&gt;&lt;!-- p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Verdana} span.s1 {letter-spacing: 0.0px} --&gt; &lt;p&gt;In Spanish schools English lessons are mandatory. Good English is seen as such a key skill that many children take extra English lessons at privately-run Academia de Inglés. While you’ll need advanced qualifications and many years’ experience to find work in state-run schools, the Academias often employ less experienced teachers. It’s also worth thinking about teaching private English lessons.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;">this will show</div>
```

Here's the problem page http://www.teflcourses.fr/tefl-jobs-abroad/

and here's an example of what it should be doing http://www.onlinetefl.com/tefl-jobs-abroad/

I can see the content is actually there in the code, so I'm just trying to figure out what could be causing innerhtml to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You use innerHtml via javascript, not declaration like you have attempted here. Put the content within the div tags ur dynamically added with a javascript function.

Comment: Hi, this is part of a existing system, which is quite extensive by the looks of it, I'm not sure if I can start reworking thier code -  more try and figure out why it's stopped working and fix - apprently it was working up to a day or so back.

Comment: I don't see how. `innerhtml` is not, and never has been, a valid attribute of `div`

Comment: Right -- I've never known to be able to decoratively set innerHtml in the construct of a div. Mro -- are you sure there's no script handling this somewhere and populating the innerHtml via javascript?

Comment: I see what you mean guys. I just found out actually (from a different source) that the issue it is google analytics causing the issue. I think this has highlighted I need to improve on my debugging/investigative work in firebug. Thanks for the help

Comment: Okay glad you found your problem -- is your code actually populating its divs from the innerhtml attribute? I never new for this to work..

Comment: I the feeling it is actually being populated by javascript - I don't think I helped matters with the question by copying the code from firebug - this is maybe how it displays through firebug ?

Comment: I think firebug should be showing exactly what the file shows. strange encounter my friend.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - if I get to the bottom of it, I'll post back.

Answer (score 0):

```
`I'm trying to figure out an issue on a site which has just stopped working.`
```

After opening the links you've provided, I have observe how the browser display this page:

- This site is not working with the latest browser.
- This site was test during development with IE7 and below.
- This site is working in IE6 and EI7

  `It seems to be anything within "innerhtml" on a tags is bieng ignored,`
  `if I put some content outside of innerhtml it shows!`

As with my observation puting the contents to `innerHTML attribute` is not working with the latest browser. I guess `innerHTML` attribute is `deprecated\remove\not included\not valid` with latest. But of course you can still use innerHTML as a property.

Then upon browsing on the js code, I find out that problem was cause by this.

```
jQuery( '#slide-browser-country-list' ).attr( 'innerHTML', cList );
```

This should be:

```
jQuery( '#slide-browser-country-list' ).html(cList);
```

Note: My search return more than one using this function.